Property of sum of lines in a triangle that originate from vertices of the triangle and intersect at a point
I have tried to solve this question through similarity, but it didn't work for me.
Question: In $\Delta ABC$, the straight lines AD,BE,CF are drawn through a point P to meet BC,CA,AB at D,E,F respectively. Prove that PD/AD +PE/BE+PF/CF=1 and AP/AD +BP/BE +CP/CF=2.
Source: Book- Challenge and Thrills of Pre-College Mathematics.
I am new to the site so please forgive me if there exist any errors.
Thanks in advance.

For the first one, $$\dfrac{PD}{AD}+\dfrac{PE}{BE}+\dfrac{PF}{CF}=\dfrac{area(PBC)}{area(ABC)}+\dfrac{area(PAC)}{area(ABC)}+\dfrac{area(PAB)}{area(ABC)}=1.$$
And then, $$\dfrac{AP}{AD}+\dfrac{PB}{BE}+\dfrac{PC}{CF}=1-\dfrac{PD}{AD}+1-\dfrac{PE}{BE}+1-\dfrac{PF}{CF}=2.$$
